# mysqlpump charset/collation troubles in Import leads to gibberish content

Tags: mysql, data-corruption

I'm having a serious problem with restoring data from a mysqlpump export (note: not mysqldump).

Situation:
MySQL 8.0.19 running on FreeBSD 12.1 running on ESXi.
I have made a clone of that machine.
So they are fully identical in OS and MySQL version and settings (except IP of course).
Let's call the first machine "source" and the second "target".

I run a full DB backup like this:

```
mysqlpump --set-gtid-purged=ON -u root -p DBName --result-file=DBName.sql
```

I copy the resulting DBName.sql file to the target host, and import it into mysql by using the command line client and `source` command in it.

Some of the tables have now corrupted gibberish data in it (collation of fields:utf8mb4_bin).
The structure of the table is fully correct (including the collation of the fields).

But if I export only the specific table with a command like this:

```
mysqlpump --set-gtid-purged=ON -u root -p DBName TABLEName --result-file=TABLEName.sql
```

I copy this to the target and import it exactly the same way, everything is correct.

I already spent one full day debugging this, as the datasets involved are massive it's not an easy task.

Anybody has a hint for me what could be the cause of this, how to resolve it or any approach to efficiently debug this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parameter --default-character-set-set to specify the exported character set, and then try again.